# Is there any difference of HID multi-touch "report descriptor" between Windows and Linux driver?

Tags: windows, linux-device-driver, multi-touch, hid

My question is if we develop a windows-based HID (multi-touch) input device and connect to a Linux device, will we encounter HID "report descriptor" compatibility issue between these two OS env ?

Look forward to your kindly answers and explanation

appreciated

Comment: Or any web-site or official document ever define different "report descriptor" of both Windows and Linux ?!

Comment: What do you mean by that all? The adaptive hardware to the OS? It is really fragile and awful way to do such. If there is one, tell us -- at least I will blacklist such a stupid vendor for my own use.